# Why when i insert a figure in a section and then move on to a new section do my figures not stay where they are suppose to be

Tags: floats

This is about the 4th or 5th time i have encountered this. Im very new to latex but I'm growing tired of not understanding why this is happening

I place a figure in document with the following code

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{currentdischarge}
}
\caption{Expected current discharge}
\end{figure}
```

Then i go and start a new section and continue on with my article

```
\section{blah blah}
```

I do a typeset to check my work and every single time my figures are no under my new section instead of where they are suppose to be!

Someone please help! I spend more time fighting latex then i do actually working

Comment: Please read [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275).

Comment: Please get us a bit of code we can use! Depending on the `documentclass` you are using, the processing behaviour or our recommendations could vary.

Answer (score 4):

use `\begin{figure}[!htb]` and the figure will be in most cases at the defined position. If you do not want the floating then don't use a float object. Use instead:

```
\usepackage{capt-of}
...
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{foo}
\captionof{figure}{bar}\label{baz}
\end{minipage}
```

With one of the KOMA-Script classes you do not need the package `capt-of`. Which is, of course, only a *oneliner*.

Comment: Ok, can someone get me a bit of code i can use that will work every time to place a picture exactly where I'm coding? The only way i know how to add pictures is with the code i used above

Comment: Herbert just did. The "problem" you are facing is called 'floating'. Minipages do not float, so like this you can force them to stay where ever you want. Still, most people here will recommend to let your images float. You should do some reading on this topic in order to see, why this makes sense for typographical reasons.

Comment: @Robert No, your code will not put a picture in the marked place. Moreover, without `!` or similar methods sometimes it is completely impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I'm sure you can imagine I'm very new to latex and like any language it has a steep learning curve. I found something online that talks about a \Floabarrier. Do you have any information on that? What method is the most accepted in practice?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: "If you do _not_ want the floating object ...."

Comment: @Robert http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/placeins/placeins-doc.pdf (and no, this is not really what you are looking for. But maybe it works if you set a barrier after each float... which makes no sense)

Comment: @Herbert Sorry, I don't follow. Did I write something confusing or did you get me wrong? My first comment was addressed to the OP.